# How to not concatenate blank inputs using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here a set of inputs that gets concatenated automatically on the last input.

The problem is, I would like to change it so that it won't concatenate empty inputs.

The way it's being used right now is the user have to manually erase the auto-generated spacing or comma by the empty input. This doesn't have to be...

Please see my simple code:

```js
$('#month2, #day2, #year2, #pl1a, #pl2a, #div2, #title2, #subtitle2, #chapter2, #subchapter2, #section2, #stat1a, #stat2a').bind('keypress blur', function() {

$('#input13').val('Act ' +
$('#month2').val() + ' ' +
$('#day2').val() + ', ' +
$('#year2').val() + ', ' + 'P.L. ' +
$('#pl1a').val() + '-' +
$('#pl2a').val() + ', ' + 'Div ' +
$('#div2').val() + ', ' + 'Title ' +
$('#title2').val() + ', ' + 'Subtitle ' +
$('#subtitle2').val() + ', ' + 'Ch ' +
$('#chapter2').val() + ', ' + 'Subch ' +
$('#subchapter2').val() + ', ' + '§ ' +
$('#section2').val() + ', ' +
$('#stat1a').val() + ' Stat. ' +
$('#stat2a').val() + ', provides:' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="month2" placeholder="Month"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="day2" placeholder="Day"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="year2" placeholder="Year"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="pl1a" placeholder="117"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="pl2a" placeholder="XXX"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="div2" placeholder="Div"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="title2" placeholder="Title"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="subtitle2" placeholder="Subtitle"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="chapter2" placeholder="Chapter"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="subchapter2" placeholder="Subchapter"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="section2" placeholder="Section"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="stat1a" placeholder="134"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="stat2a" placeholder="Page"/>
</form>
<form class="mt-3" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn no-enter" type="text" id="input13" placeholder="Result"/>
</form>
```

Additionally, if those empty inputs won't be concatenated, it means I now have to change my code a little bit since it auto-generate some important text after the input for the next input, so that it will instead add it before the input information.

e.g.

```
$('#div2').val() + ', ' + 'Title ' +
$('#title2').val() + ', ' + 'Subtitle ' +
```

The "Title" string after the "div2" input should be a part of the input below it, preceding the "Title" input and so on...

like this:

```
$'Title ' + ('#title2').val() + ', '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
$('#month2, #day2, #year2, #pl1a, #pl2a, #div2, #title2, #subtitle2, #chapter2, #subchapter2, #section2, #stat1a, #stat2a').bind('keypress blur', function() {

function date() {
   var m = $('#month2').val();
   var d = $('#day2').val();
   var y = $('#year2').val();
   if (m && d && y) {
      return 'Act ' + m + ' ' + d + ', ' + y;
   }
}
function pla() {
  var p1 = $('#pl1a').val();
  var p2 = $('#pl2a').val();
  if (p1 && p2) {
     return 'P.L. ' + p1 + '-' + p2;
  }
}
function getValue(element, prefix = '') {
  var value = $(element).val();
  if (value) {
    return prefix + value;
  }
}
// filter will remove empty elements when function return undefined
$('#input13').val([
   date(),
   pla(),
   getValue('#div2', 'Div '),
   getValue('#title2', 'Title '),
   getValue('#subtitle2', 'Subtitle '),
   getValue('#chapter2', 'Ch '),
   getValue('#subchapter2','Subch '),
   getValue('#stat1a'),
   getValue('#stat2a', ' Stat. '),
   'provides:'
].filter(Boolean).join(', '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="month2" placeholder="Month"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="day2" placeholder="Day"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="year2" placeholder="Year"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="pl1a" placeholder="117"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="pl2a" placeholder="XXX"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="div2" placeholder="Div"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="title2" placeholder="Title"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="subtitle2" placeholder="Subtitle"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="chapter2" placeholder="Chapter"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="subchapter2" placeholder="Subchapter"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="section2" placeholder="Section"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="stat1a" placeholder="134"/> <br/>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 no-enter" type="text" id="stat2a" placeholder="Page"/>
</form>
<form class="mt-3" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn no-enter" type="text" id="input13" placeholder="Result"/>
</form>
```

If you have code that is little bit complex than you can handle split the code into a functions.

Comment: Woah this is a very neat solution! I've tested it and it's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your time creating this script!